# Show WHOIS in IP reference box

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

When a moderator clicks on a user's IP address, it shows their location by GeoIP and the reverse DNS lookup. It would be helpful if we could also get a WHOIS lookup - the box could display who the registered owner was, and there could be a link to the full WHOIS query results. This would be useful when trying to determine if a potential spammer is associated with a service, if their WHOIS shows that they're posting from the company being advertised, etc.

Comment: Ideally I'd also like it to include a satellite picture of their house and a list of their loved ones

Comment: And a _nuke from orbit_ button.