# Non-gravatar profile pictures in Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-picture

[Now that we've got non-gravatar profile pictures](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/announcing-a-new-way-to-change-your-profile-picture/), we should have the same functionality in careers. It still only allows gravatar pictures.

<sub>There's an [old pre-native picture question][2] asking basically the same, but seeing that it has an accepted answer I created a new one.</sub>

Comment: @Will is this still planned?

Comment: @WillCole is this still planned?

Comment: @WillCole any news on this?

Comment: I want the same feature. It is available in SO, but not in Career 2.0. I don't want to use gravatar because it shows my picture in every Wordpress blog when I leave comment or question despite I want to share my picture or not.

Comment: Why does such a basic feature take so long to be implemented ? **I don't want to create a stupid Wordpress account just to put a picture on Careers.**

Comment: @Will almost three years later, any updates? We'll also take a "No" as an answer

Comment: I am very annoyed how Gravatar [doesn't work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269793/so-careers-should-not-be-gravatar-only). Please, give an alternative!

Comment: @MikhailGolubtsov finally we got official response, see Laura's answer. (I got notification having a bounty, but you didn't)

Comment: @Laura does removing the [tag:status-planned] mean it is not planned anymore? In such case can you please edit the answer accordingly?

Comment: /cc @Will - since it's your edit that added the tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard it's still planned but I am trying to have us be better about only using the tag when someone is actively scheduled to work on or is already working on something and it's release is imminent. This problem likely won't be solved til March, which seems too far away to warrant a status-planned.

Comment: @Laura so you're surely the first one... take a look in the tag questions list, most of them sit with the planned status for months and years, e.g. [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97921/show-whois-in-ip-reference-box) for over four years. :)

Comment: I know @Sha...I started going through them before the holidays and noticed how long some of them have had that tag. Trying to lead by example, but I'll also go through and update more of the others.

Comment: Thanks @Laura - by the way, your last comment didn't notify me due to the dots - it works in chat, but not in comments. Anyway thanks again and highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the lack of response here. We've always intended to do this, but it turns out that fixing this was more complicated than simply copying the implementation we have on Stack Overflow.

Our development and design resources are stretched pretty thin at the moment, so I can't make promises that this will be resolved immediately or in the next couple of weeks, but this pain point is still there, we're still aware of it, and I am confident we'll eliminate it in the next 6 months. Thanks for your patience – bear with us just a little bit longer.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Time to retag as [tag:status-really-planned]? :-D