# Planned or reproduced status means the same thing or are they not being used properly

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, moderator-tags

Why do we need two tags and what are the differences.

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) and [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) mean the same thing. It means that the proposition was accepted or that the bug was confirmed and that the fix or modification is on the way. At first, I thought that the [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) was only for feature request but it seems that a lot of moderators are using it for bugs too.

Bug with planned :

- [Error when commenting or answering on a site where you are not registered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213816/error-when-commenting-or-answering-on-a-site-where-you-are-not-registered)

Bug with reproduced :

- [Is there a problem with the ClearBits data dump?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213670/is-there-a-problem-with-the-clearbits-data-dump)

[Is it that some moderators are mistagging bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned+bug) or is one of the two tags futile ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) and [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) mean the same thing

Nope, I don't agree. Here is how I see it:

- [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) means the bug was reproduced. Nothing less and nothing more. It **does not** mean the team is going to  spend time fixing it. They might, or not.
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) means the team is planning to fix the bug or implement the feature request. Nothing more and nothing less... it might take few minutes, 6-8 weeks, or 6-8 years. :)

That said, we're all humans. Including the dev team... so sometimes they put status-planned tag and it's forgotten, sometimes it gets done but they forget to  change to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) etc.

We can [nudge the dev in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97921/show-whois-in-ip-reference-box#comment683182_97921), he might reply at some point. The key here is patience.

Comment: This is how I interpret them as well.

Comment: So sometimes, the team finds a bug but does not plan on fixing it. Good to know.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname yes indeed, if they find it too minor, like all the plural bugs (e.g. 1 answers)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Makes sense. Thanks !